# Plane geometry problem to find triangle side's length

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle where a point $K$ on $AB$ such that $AK:KB=2:3$ and on the side $AC$ is a point $L$ such that $AL:LC=5:3$. The intersection of $CK$ and $BL$ is  $P$. $PH \perp AB$ and $PH = 1,5$. My question is what is the length of $AB$?

$\\$
I've used Menelaus' theorem for triangles $ABL$ and $ACK$. My results are $BP:PL = 4$, $CP = PK$. I have a strong suspicion that the answer is $AB = \frac{5}{4}PH = 1.875$. I believe that we need to draw some other lines. Any hints or ideas?

Comment: I agree that there is not enough info. Take any triangle with height to $AB$ equal $7.5$ and you can construct $CK$ and $BL$ with the given conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your question cannot be solved. You are right that $CP = PK$ by Menelaus theorem. We use coordinate geometry. If $A = (0,0), B = (5a,0), C = (8b,8c)$, then $L = (5b,5c)$ and $K (2a,0)$. The fact that $PH = 1.5$ simply tells us that $4c = 1.5$ hence $c = 0.375$. The length of $AB$, which is $5a$, is not determined from $c$, in other words, we can set any $a$ and $b$ and get different answer while still conforming the question. We might need additional info to crack this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been able to solve the question with additional info $S_{ABC} = 6$. Now the problem is easy and $AB$ = 4